# Can you perform a UNION without a subquery in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

[Another question shows how to do a union in SQLAlchemy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032394/565879)

Is it possible to perform a union in SQLAlchemy without using a subquery?

For example, in the linked question SQLAlchemy produces SQL of the form:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT column_a FROM table_a UNION SELECT column_b FROM table_b)`

But I would like SQLAlchemy to produce SQL like:

`SELECT column_a FROM table_a UNION SELECT column_b FROM table_b`

The latter SQL is shorter, doesn't use a subquery, and does the same thing. Can SQLAlchemy produces a union like the latter query?

Comment: `session.execute(s1.union(s2))`?

Comment: @univerio No. If you print s1.union(s2) you'll see it's using a subquery.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [SQLAlchemy SQL Expression Language Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#unions-and-other-set-operations):

You can use [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html?highlight=union#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union):

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import union
u = union(
    addresses.select().where(addresses.c.email_address == 'foo@bar.com'),
    addresses.select().where(addresses.c.email_address.like('%@yahoo.com')),
).order_by(addresses.c.email_address)
u.compile()
```

This produces:

```sql
SELECT
    addresses.id,
    addresses.user_id,
    addresses.email_address
FROM addresses WHERE addresses.email_address = ?

UNION

SELECT
    addresses.id,
    addresses.user_id,
    addresses.email_address
FROM addresses
WHERE addresses.email_address LIKE ?
ORDER BY addresses.email_address
```

Params: `('foo@bar.com', '%@yahoo.com')`